# How to programmatically (C#) read Windows Server Task Scheduler job history/log

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I have multiple scheduled jobs on a windows Server that run every night starting at 9 PM till midnight.
Is there any programmatic way (C#) to read (export) the Logs/History of each scheduled task and save it to SQL Server or as a text file  within the server.
We are tying to show that data on a dashboard. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I have researched on this issue and found a solution that worked for me. Created a sample project and is on GitHub.
Please check it out [GetTaskSchedulerHistory](https://github.com/VijayaMalla/GetTaskSchedulerHistory)

Thank You